# Parse expression with functions

Tags: algorithm, function, parsing, expression

This is my situation: the input is a string that contains a normal mathematical operation like `5+3*4`. Functions are also possible, i.e. `min(5,A*2)`. This string is already tokenized, and now I want to parse it using stacks (so no AST). I first used the Shunting Yard Algorithm, but here my main problem arise:

Suppose you have this (tokenized) string: `min(1,2,3,+)` which is obviously invalid syntax. However, SYA turns this into the output stack `1 2 3 + min(`, and hopefully you see the problem coming. When parsing from left to right, it sees the `+` first, calculating `2+3=5`, and then calculating `min(1,5)`, which results in 1. Thus, my algorithm says this expression is completely fine, while it should throw a syntax error (or something similar).

What is the best way to prevent things like this? Add a special delimiter (such as the comma), use a different algorithm, or what?

Comment: There's pseudocode for a Shunting-Yard parser which understands function calls in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392115/1566221). Note that when the pseudocode tells you to "mark `(` as a postfix operator", that means you need to treat it as a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent this issue, you might have to keep track of the stack depth. The way I would do this (and I'm not sure it is the "best" way) is with another stack.

The new stack follows these rules:

- When an open parentheses, `(`, or function is parsed, push a `0`.

  - Do this in case of nested functions
- When a closing parentheses, `)`, is parsed, pop the last item off and add it to the new last value on the stack.

  - The number that just got popped off is how many values were returned by the function. You probably want this to always be `1`.
- When a comma or similar delimiter is parsed, pop from the stack, add that number to the new last element, then push a 0.

  - Reset so that we can begin verifying the next argument of a function
  - The value that just got popped off is how many values were returned by the statement. You probably want this to always be `1`.
- When a number is pushed to the `output`, increment the top element of this stack.

  - This is how many values are available in the `output`. Numbers increase the number of values. Binary operators need to have at least 2.
- When a binary operator is pushed to the `output`, decrement the top element

  - A binary operator takes 2 values and outputs 1, thus reducing the overall number of values left on the output by 1.
  - In general, an *n*-ary operator that takes *n* values and returns *m* values should add (*m-n*) to the top element.
  - If this value ever becomes negative, throw an error!

This will find that the last argument in your example, which just contains a `+`, will decrement the top of the stack to `-1`, automatically throwing an error.

But then you might notice that a final argument in your example of, say, `3+` would return a zero, which is not negative. In this case, you would throw an error in one of the steps where "you probably want this to always be 1."